# XSLT - Put node in to white space

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like follows,

```
<session>
    <p> This is first sentence</p>
    <p>          This is second sentance</p>
<session>
```

what I need is inset new node named `<s>` to every space in `<p>` content. number of consecutive space should be show as attribute of `<s>` node.

I've written following xsl to do this,

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()" priority="10">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&#x0020;">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:if test="position() gt 0">
          <tps:s c="{position()}"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```

the result of this code is follows,

```
 <session>
    <p><s c="1"/> This<s c="3"/> is<s c="5"/> first<s c="7"/> sentence</p>
    <p><s c="1"/> <s c="2"/> <s c="3"/> <s c="4"/> <s c="5"/> <s c="6"/> <s c="7"/> <s c="8"/> <s c="9"/> <s c="10"/> This<s c="12"/> is<s c="14"/> second<s c="16"/> sentance</p>
  </session>
```

As it shown above it adds `<s>` for every space and but what I'm expecting is follows,

```
 <session>
    <p><s c="1"/>This<s c="1"/> is<s c="1"/> first<s c="1"/> sentence</p>
    <p><s c="10"/> This<s c="1"/> is<s c="1"/> second<s c="1"/> sentance</p>
  </session>
```

I tried to use variable but it did not succeed since variables are not varying in xslt. Can anyone suggest me a method to arrange my code to get expected output.

Thanks in adnanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply match on a sequence of blanks and count them:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&#x0020;+">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
      <tps:s c="{string-length()}"/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
```

The rest of your code remains unchanged.